# Swift 3 struct to parameter for Alamofire4

Tags: ios, json, struct

Iam new in Swift and i want to convert my struct into parameter to post it with Alamofire 4.
Please excuse my bad english.

My struct is in another Class:

```
import Foundation
```

class structUser: NSObject{

```
var myStructUser = [person]()


struct person {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var age: Int
    init ( firstName : String, lastName : String, age : Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age

    }
}

override init(){
    myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 11))
    myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Brauer", age : 22))
    myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "Merrideth", lastName: "Lind", age : 55))
}
```

}

now in the Main Class I want to post the Alamofire, but how can I convert only the first name and the age from the struct?

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let classStructUser = structUser()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print(classStructUser.myStructUser)
}


func postJson(){
    //need format [String : Any]
    for item in classStructUser.myStructUser{
        // var name = classStructUser.myStructUser.name
        // var age = classStructUser.myStructUser.age

    }

  print(classStructUser.myStructUser)

    /*here i need the Json in format:

    {
    "name":"John",
    "age":11
     }

     {
     "name":"Richard",
     "age":22
     }

     {
     "name":"Merrideth",
     "age":55
     }


     an so on array.count
     */
}
```

}

another Question:

How can I access a variable in the struct(structUser) from VieControllerClass

thx for your help! And please explain the full solution, because i want to understand how ist works. 
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class structUser: NSObject{

    var myStructUser = [person]()

    struct person {
        var firstName : String
        var lastName : String
        var age: Int
        init ( firstName : String, lastName : String, age : Int) {
            self.firstName = firstName
            self.lastName = lastName
            self.age = age

        }

        static func jsonArray(array : [person]) -> String
        {
            return "[" + array.map {$0.jsonRepresentation}.joined(separator: ",") + "]"
        }

        var jsonRepresentation : String {
            return "{\"name\":\"\(firstName)\",\"age\":\"\(age)\"}"
        }
    }

    func jsonRepresentation() -> String {
        return person.jsonArray(array: myStructUser)
    }

    override init(){
        myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 11))
        myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "Richard", lastName: "Brauer", age : 22))
        myStructUser.append(person(firstName: "Merrideth", lastName: "Lind", age : 55))
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
let jsonString = classStructUser.myStructUser.jsonRepresentation()
```

Comment: And that's all? How can i choose only name and age?

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll test it! Can you maybe answer my second question too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The Problem from this answer ist, that i only get a string. I cant .post IT by alamofire cos Alamofire needs [String : Any] .can i convert the String to pass the parameter? Or can i use another function? to Post this to a http Server?

Comment: Please edit your question it's mis leading, You don't need JSON then.

Comment: ? Sorry In the end i need a function to Post the json? to a http Server. I thought i could use alamofire and alamofire needs Parameter in Format [String : Any]. Can i usw another function to post the string.? Edit Sorry i misunderstood that json ist only a Syntax. I thought its some special.